# Can't get form to validate

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have to make a form that has a username and password but the password must be five or more characters. I have tried a lot of different methods but none have succeded.

Here's my javascript:

```
funtion validateForm(){
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
if (password.length < 5)
  alert("Password must be longer");
  return false;
}
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script src="js/script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="error">

        </div>
        <form name="formname" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="validateForm()" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input id="username" name="name" type="text" required>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is not bound to any event, it's running once on script load, so it won't work as expected. You need to listen for some event like blur or input on your form field

Comment: Im sorry i dont quite understand

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the form submit on validation fail.  And to do that you need to pass the event to your handler like `onsubmit="validateForm(event)"`.

See the code snippet to understand how it works.

```js
function validateForm(event) {

  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
 
  if (password.length < 5) {
    event.preventDefault();    // <--- ADDED
    alert("Password must be longer");
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="error">

</div>
<form name="formname" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="validateForm(event)" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input id="username" name="name" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```